# Trestle Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident WebApi error

Tags: json, incapsula, trestle-admin

I'm working with Trestle which is real estate MLS service to get property data etc. I have followed their WebApi docs but I'm getting this error whenever I hit their api it looks like their server thinks that request is from some BOT. Even they recommend using Postman to test api:

[image]

Its been 3 days and still cant find any fix. Any help?

Comment: Incapsula allows sites to block based on geography, which might be relevant for a real estate API.

Comment: Yes this was the case, I tried with vpn and api worked so it means this api is only accessible to certain countries

Comment: @Zayn If this is still going on, please contact us at trestlesupport@corelogic.com. We can manually unblock your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be following this documentation correctly.
https://docs-trestle.corelogic.com/GettingStarted/WebAPI

At the moment you are entering the token URL (https://api-prod.corelogic.com/trestle/oidc/connect/token) in the main Postman request URL field. The documentation states that you should use the Get New Access Token button on the Authorization tab of a request. You are entering the token URL in the main Postman request URL field.

This is a default flow for oAuth 2.0 requests in Postman.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/#oauth-20

**Example:**
This could be your request to retrieve data:

`https://api-prod.corelogic.com/trestle/odata/$metadata`

On the Authorization tab you should select *oAuth 2.0*; select *Get New Access Token* and you will see a view which gives you the functionality you are looking for.

When successful, you will get a pop-up which you need to accept in order to use the API.

Comment: Yes there are two methods, one is by using oAuth2.0 and other one is by hitting main url, I also tried by oAuth2.0 but no luck there too, got same error

Comment: Error: Could not complete OAuth 2.0 token request: {"<html style":"\"height:100%\"><head><META NAME=\"ROBOTS\" CONTENT=\"NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW\"><meta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"telephone=no\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\"><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\"></head><body style=\"margin:0px;height:100%\"><iframe id=\"main-iframe\" src=\"/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=22","xinfo":"5-188966634-0%200NNN%20RT%281581686116943%20352%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%200%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B16%20U6","incident_id":"459001820218565795-617048919130189 .....